# PHP break not working

Tags: php, date, if-statement, break

I am trying to disable a form on weekends. In my code I have a break after the variable $noaccess. When I run the code the form does not load. I am not sure what is going on please help.
 Here is my code:

```
$wkday = date('D');
if ($wkday == "Sun") {
            $noaccess = "yes";
            break;
} elseif ($currday == "Sat") {
            $noaccess = "yes";
} else {
         $noaccess = "no";
}
```

Here is the code for displaying the form:

```
if ($noaccess == "yes") {
echo "You cannot access this area now";
} else {
//Form displays normally 
}
```

Comment: *"When I run the code the form does not load."* - Show us the form and how you're using it.

Comment: `$currday` is undefined, and the `break;` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing the wrong variable `$currday` in `elseif ($currday == "Sat")`

which should be `$wkday` as in `elseif ($wkday == "Sat")` in reference to `$wkday = date('D');`

Plus as Dave Goten said, the `break;` *is unnecessary.*

Add `exit;`, `die;` or `return;` if necessary.

```
$wkday = date('D');
if ($wkday == "Sun") {
            $noaccess = "yes";
} elseif ($wkday == "Sat") {
            $noaccess = "yes";
} else {
         $noaccess = "no";
}

// test echo

if ($noaccess == "yes") {
echo "You cannot access this area now";
} else {
//Form displays normally 

echo $noaccess; // test variable echo
echo "You have access";

}
```

---

Basic debugging such as [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have signaled the undefined variable ***on that given day.***

I.e.: `Notice: Undefined variable: currday...`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

*Plus,* make sure your form looks similar to the following:

```
//Form displays normally
echo "<form action='' method='post'>"; // or get. I have no idea what you're using
echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

...since you have not included that in your question. Just to make sure there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

use the or operator to simplify your logic and then there is no need to use the break.

```
   if ($wkday == "Sun" || $wkday == "Sat") {
                $noaccess = "yes";
    } else {
             $noaccess = "no";
    }
```